# Uploading common required file via FTP without affecting website?

Tags: php, ftp

Lets say I have a file `common.php` used by many pages in my website. Now I want to update the file via FTP, so there will be around 1-2 seconds where the file is not available / still partially being uploaded.

During that time, it causes `require('common.php')` to report error, thus website is not loading properly.

How to solve cases like this?

Thanks!

Comment: It's unavoidable - but you can always forward your users to a temporary page, [like in this article](https://davidwalsh.name/htaccess-maintenance-page-redirect), while the change takes place, then rescind the changes made to `.htaccess`

Comment: You can Upload new  common.php with different name e.g. common-new.php >> Rename Old common.php e.g. common-old.php  >> rename common-new.php To common.php.....Renaming is more fast than Upload Time....What i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload the file with a different name and rename it only after the upload completes. That minimizes the downtime.

Some clients support this even automatically. What further minimizes the downtime.

For example, [WinSCP SFTP/FTP client](https://winscp.net/) supports this. But with SFTP protocol only, if that's an option for you.

In WinSCP preferences, enable *[Transfer to temporary filename](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_resume)* for *All files*.

WinSCP will then [upload all files with a temporary `.filepart` extension](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/resume#automatic), overwriting the target file only after the upload finishes.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: WinSCP really gives what I need, except I am using Mac OS :( anyway i got the idea. thanks!